# Can Soundness and Completeness be shown for finite sets?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I am stuck as to how one would show a proof system is sound and complete assuming that we are using only finite sets, $\Omega $.  In other words, knowing that for any finite set of formulas $\Omega $ and any formula $\phi$,  $Ω ⊢ φ  ⟺  Ω⊨φ$,  how would I be able to show soundness and completeness?

Comment: You can check every statement, if only finite many cases are possible, by exhaustive search.

Comment: May you provide some more elements regarding the source of your question, please? *Soundness* is a "property" of the rules of the system and does not depend on the number of premises used.